# How to only let user transfer funds from wallet which belongs to his account in django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from djmoney.models.fields import MoneyField

# Create your models here.
class Account(models.Model):
    # ACCOUNT_TYPES = (
    #     ('PERSONAL', 'PERSONAL'),
    #     ('BUSINESS', 'BUSINESS')
    # )

    account_owner = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    account_number = models.CharField(max_length=15, unique=True)

    # account_type = models.CharField(max_length=17, choices=ACCOUNT_TYPES)
    balance = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=3)

    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.account_number


class Transaction(models.Model):
    account_owner = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CharField, null=True)
    from_account = models.CharField(max_length=15)

    to_account = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=3)

    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.amount)
```

views.py

```
@login_required
def transfer(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = forms.TransactionForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            sender = models.Account.objects.get(account_number=request.POST.get('from_account'))
            if sender.balance > decimal.Decimal(request.POST.get('amount')):
                trans = form.save()
                trans.account_owner = request.user

                # debit the sender account
                sender.balance -= decimal.Decimal(request.POST.get('amount'))
                sender.save()

                # credit receiver account
                receiver = models.Account.objects.get(account_number=request.POST.get('to_account'))
                receiver.balance += decimal.Decimal(request.POST.get('amount'))
                receiver.save()

                return render(request, "wallet.html")


    else:
        form = forms.TransactionForm()
        return render(request, "wallet.html", {'form': form})
```

Hi, I am having trouble with this, transferring funds from one account to another is working great but I only want the user's account number to be able to transfer who is logged in...not this that I can input anyone's account number and transfer from one account to another...I just want to make sure the account number belongs to the user logged in and only that is the from_account. Thanks! I really need help on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a functioning authentication system, you can:

`try:
    Account.objects.get(account_number=request.POST.get('from_account'), account_owner=request.user)
except Account.DoesNotExist: # you should be catching this anyway in case form_account is wrong
    raise ValidationError("some error message")`

To make things cleaner, look into how you can relay the validation logic to the django form you are using.
`

Comment: not working, it says positional argument follows keyword argument (<unknown>, line

Comment: how do. I just make sure that the account_number matches the logged in user? I am using django User model and everything like. login, logout and sign up works.

Comment: `Account.objects.get(account_number=request.POST.get('from_account'), account_owner=request.user)`   I can't check it for errors completely because it runs on your machine.

Answer (score 0):

Your Account models structure is good, but the Transaction model isn't, here is why:

> The model itself doesn't contain any logic for transferring funds. Fund transfer logic should be handled in a method that sender and the receiver are in ForeignKey to a CustomUser model.

Using ForeignKey to CustomUser model in the Transaction model will make sure that the sender and receiver are valid users in the system, and you can access user-related information easily, and even throwing an error if the sender account number isn't equal to receiver account number.

```
from django.conf import settings

class Transaction(models.Model):
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=3)
    sender = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='sender')
    receiver = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='receiver')
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    to_account = models.IntegerField()
```

Here is how you can send funds to a login in user account:

```
from django.contrib import messages

def transfer(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        '''
        '''
        receiver_account = Account.objects.get(account_owner=request.user)

        if receiver_account.account_number != to_account:

            messages.error(request, 'Invalid Account Number')

            return redirect('Transfer')
        else:
            receiver_account.balance += amount

            receiver_account.save()

            Transaction.objects.create(
                sender=request.user, receiver=receiver_account.account_owner,
                amount=amount, to_account=to_account
             )
    else:
        form = forms.TransactionForm()
    return render(request, "wallet.html", {'form': form})
```